# JQuery Player - Doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am using a music player written in Jquery which I converted it into a radio player.

The problem is It doesn't work on google chrome

In my index.php file, (written in html5 also) I have created the object with these features

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
  {
    //m4a: "http://46.20.4.50:8030/",   //Safari & Fenomen
    m4a: "http://stream-uk1.radioparadise.com:8034",
    oga: "http://stream-sd.radioparadise.com:9000/rp_192m.ogg" //Firefox
    //m4a :"muzikler/0.m4a",
    //oga :"muzikler/0.ogg"
  }, {
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
    canplay: function() {
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
    }
  });
});
```

I was wondering if chrome doesn't support .ogg or .m4a but I don't think so since I ve tried it on another player.

In the .js file I ve also adapted jquery 1.4.4 since 1.3.2 doesnt detect Chrome as webkit.

```
$.jPlayer.uaBrowser = function( userAgent ) {
  var ua = userAgent.toLowerCase();

  // Useragent RegExp
  var rwebkit = /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/;
  var ropera = /(opera)(?:.*version)?[ \/]([\w.]+)/;
  var rmsie = /(msie) ([\w.]+)/;
  var rmozilla = /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+))?/;
  var match = rwebkit.exec( ua ) ||
              ropera.exec( ua ) ||
              rmsie.exec( ua ) ||
              ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && rmozilla.exec( ua ) ||
              [];
  return { browser: match[1] || "", version: match[2] || "0" };
};
```

What part am I actually missing to fix this issue?

You can take a look at the full js file : http://pastebin.com/HVKGXkCy

Comment: So whats your reason for detecting what browser is used? That's usually a sign you're doing something a little wrong. jQuery already does something like this, but its deprecated and removed in the most recent versions because theres usually not a good reason to use it; the point is to use feature detection instead. Anyways: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: Understood, thank you! What if I integrate     `$.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());` (ill change it for this function). Would it also work?

Comment: Or integrating `/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/;` directly as a new variable? I'm missing some part since I still cant get them work as intented.